# Mapping in MATLAB - TVMap style (square boxes)

Tags: matlab, mapping

I want to make a map of the U.S. and plot grid cells onto it. Each grid cell has a data value and will be filled in with a color from a colorbar.

In IDL, maybe in a special package, I'm not sure, there's a command called tvmap that does this. I don't know how to replicate it in MATLAB.

It should look like this:

[image: Map of U.S. with data in each model box]

I have the 'lat' and 'lon' values as a column of numbers. Each lat and lon pair defines the CENTER of a box. A 'data' variable contains the value that is supposed to go into that box.

Here's what I have so far. This part just creates a map of the U.S. and a colorbar. I don't know how to map colored grids onto it.

```
figure(1);
ax = usamap('conus');
set(ax, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]); 
states = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true,...
   'Selector',...
   {@(name) ~any(strcmp(name,{'Alaska','Hawaii'})), 'Name'});
geoshow(ax, states,'FaceColor', 'none', 'EdgeColor', [0.5 0.5 0.5])
framem off; gridm off; mlabel off; plabel off
set(gca,'Visible','on'); 

hold on

% Colorbar
caxis([10 80]);
h = colorbar('location', 'EastOutside');
ylabel(h,'MDA8 O_3');

% Title
title(['Correlation Between Monthly Mean Obs and Base Simulation in ', cell2mat(cellstr(years))]); % Title changes every daytitle(str);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pcolorm(lat,lon,data)` does the trick. Make sure lat and lon and data are the same size. In terms of a map, that means making a matrix of lat and lon values corresponding to each data point.

The result (with dots plotted on top) looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
image
```

is the command you are looking for.